# Elasticsearch does not start automatically when I restart the server

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to make Elasticsearch start automatically when I restart the server by following the steps [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rpm.html#rpm-running-systemd).

The problem is that When I restart the server, `/tmp` is being mounted with the `noexec` option and I need to run `mount -o remount,exec /tmp` and manually start Elasticsarch again.

Someone told me that I need to remove `noexec` from `/etc/fstab` but `noexec` is not there.

**Edit:**

I think that the `noexec` option might be added by `/scripts/securetmp`
When I run `mount` I see:

```
/usr/tmpDSK on /tmp type ext3 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
/usr/tmpDSK on /var/tmp type ext3 (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,data=ordered)
```

Comment: this is not elastic issue. did you install  with deb package?

Comment: @hamidbayat With RPM, on a CentOS 7

Comment: what do you have in `/etc/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/tmp.mount` file?

Comment: @IanGabes I have the dir `/etc/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants` but there's no `tmp.mount` file.

Comment: What files are in that folder?

Comment: Thanks @IanGabes, I just solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by deactivating `/scripts/securetmp`. For more information, look at [this post](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/separating-var-tmp-from-tmp.318601/).

I extracted the steps just in case the post disappears in the future.

Run

```
# /scripts/securetmp
```

Is going to appear this:

```
Would you like to secure /tmp & /var/tmp at boot time? (y/n)
```

Type `n`

Is going to appear this:

```
securetmp will not be added to system startup at this time.
Would you like to disable securetmp from the system startup? (y/n)
```

Type `y`

Is going to appear this:

```
Would you like to secure /tmp & /var/tmp now? (y/n)
```

Type `n`

Is going to appear this:

```
/tmp & /var/tmp will not be secured at this time.
```